# C# Is there a way to wait for action callback after executing a method

Tags: c#

I have a legacy code library that provides the following method signature

```
void DoWork(IEnumerable<IMessage> message,
                         Action<IEnumerable<IMessage>, Exception> onErrorCallBack,
                         Action<IEnumerable<IMessage>> onCompletionCallBack);
```

When I call this method in my code, I am unable to wait for the onErrorCallBack and starts executing the next line of code. Is there a way to wait for the callbacks to arrive and then proceed to the next line? This is getting more worst if i fire this method inside a parallel for loop. The loop continues without waiting for the callback and results in many calls bogging down my system resources. Any respite?

Comment: What if there's no error and `onErrorCallback` doesn't get called?

Comment: You can "wrap" this call to use it with async/await - I have marked your question as a duplicate of another one which describes this technique. If this solution is not applicable to your situation, just explain why and I will remove the duplicate lock.

Comment: @phuzi: If there is no error, the success block is called. Error block is optional, to be called only when the called method throws an exception.

Comment: @Heinzi: The other thread describes the approach with one callback. Can that be extended to cater to multiple callbacks?

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran: Sure, just make it a `TaskCompletionSource<(IEnumerable<IMessage>, Exception)>`. In the error case, set the exception, in the success case, set it to  null.

Comment: @Heinzi: Thank you. When I tried it, I was missing the paranthesis ( ) and it was throwing error.

Comment: Not sure about "multiple" callbacks, but since the other one is an indication of error, the `onErrorCallback` would be `(_, e) => t.TrySetException(e);` (where `t` is a `TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<IMessage>>`).